# Atom editor to webserver and to GitHub synchronize

Tags: git, github, atom-editor

What I want to do (and I need some help with setup):

1) I work remotely with Atom editor

2) When I save my files or doing some changes, I want send them to GitHub repository (commit & pull I guess...) + save it on my web server

How can I do that from atom? Is it possible?

(I have GitHub client for window + atom editor + GitHub repository...)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Git Plus package at https://atom.io/packages/git-plus

This package allows you to do the most important Git commands from within Atom.

For you this probably is adding the changes files, committing them and pushing the commit to the online repository. For this common use case Git Plus also has the "Git add all commit and push" command.